# Australian visa subclass 189

Tags: visa, working-visas, immigration, australia

I plan to apply for Australia subclass 189 visa for myself and my partner and am looking to confirm some of the details.

1. For the Skilled Occupations Lists: I know that my skill should be on the nominated skills list for us to get 5 points. Should our skills be the same skills or do the partner's skills matter?
2. The Skilled Occupations List is very specific, and the university information is general. How can I know which skills on the list are matched with my degree? For example, if the degree is in economics, which skills does it match?
3. If someone gets 60 points, what percentage is needed to be accepted?
4. If I'm living in a country that does not charge taxes, what documents should be provided to prove work experience?

Comment: A degree isn't enough, you need work experience. What job is connected with the economics degree? The closest I saw on the list was accountancy. Whatever the skill, one of the Australia regulatory bodies will assess your skills. Check with the applicable one on what they want or will accept. (generally certified letters from employers detailing what work you do)

Comment: the question is (should the partners skill (degree ) be the same , or it is ok if their skills are different  ?

Comment: Yes, it's okay if the skills are different. I think the work skills of the partner do not matter though (but I could be wrong) because they're usually entering on a dependent visa of the primary immigrant. If the primary applicant is approved, the partner will automatically get permission to work once they emigrate.

Answer (score 2):

1. You do not get points for 'Nominated Skill' - you can not apply if it is not in the list. You get 5 points from that specific state if they are looking for people in that profession. There is slight difference...
2. Before you choose one, you need to think what kind of references and diploma you can provide to get most points. Look for requirements in specific agency in Australia that is responsible for 'validating' your references your diploma etc, in my case it was [ACS](https://more.acs.org.au/migration-skills-assessment)
3. Every month they will go through all applicants and will first get those who have 75 points, if there are places they will go though 70, 65... then if they filled quota for that month but not all apllicants lets say at 65 got invited, they will keep uninvited 65s on the applicant list ordered by application date for the next month... then rince and repeat each month.. If they have to many 70 they might bump requirement to 70... Point I am trying to make 60 is not static...
4. Your references in following format (for ASC, for other agency format is likelly to be different)... you will have to get originals the to Australian Embasy to get notarized...

[image]